# Seaching dll problem

Tags: cmd

Is this the right code for searching in cmd? Please check it..

c:\windows\assembly\ a\s\w healthcare*.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DIR path\part-name*.dll /s
```

or in your special case

```
DIR %windir%\*healtcare*.* /s
```

where part-name stays for *"part of file name you're searching"*.